# How can I set the starting folder for new shells using gnome-terminal when launching from xfe?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I like to use **xfe** because it's quick and I make use of the 3 panes. I'm using ubuntu and I like using **gnome-terminal** but I can't get xfe to launch gnome-terminal with the bash shell in the same folder as the xfe pane.

In xfe, if you press ctrl-t it'll open xterm (by default) in the current folder. I'd like that to happen in gnome-terminal instead. Sometimes I get errors, sometimes it just doesn't put me into the desired folder.

I've tried a few things

- using parameters with the -- and the -x (which tells me is deprecated in favor of --).
- I've created a script and tried cd $@ and $@ in various forms surrounded by double quotes and not
- Used a script to populate the --working-directory= surrounded by quotes and not

It works rather seamlessly without a lot of effort for *xfce4-terminal*, and I may just switch to that over xterm, but I'd still like to get it to work with gnome-terminal.

I think there's some confusion about "working directory"... i'm actually looking for bash to start in that directory once the terminal program opens, not necessarily that the terminal program itself starts in or uses the "working directory".

Ultimately, I want the output of pwd in a new terminal from xfe to be equal to the path of the selected pane in xfe. Call it whatever you want. The above are just some things that I tried.

Comment: You can copy its `.desktop` file and make one with a different setting for the working directory. Internally, it's just a text file.

Comment: edited question as attempt to clarify desired end state vs "working directory".

Comment: It's looking precisely like you are confused about that. Bash will inherit the current working directory of the terminal you start. Maybe see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory/66860904)

Comment: thanks for the link. Can you tell me how to start gnome-terminal so that the folder the new shell's current folder is the same as the folder from which I pressed ctrl-t in xfe? I think you know what I'm looking for and are just being critical which isn't really helpful.

Comment: tried again, open to suggestions on how to improve the question without steering me in the wrong direction. good luck with your mission to educate the world on current working directory.

Comment: I have no direct experience with XFE, or I would attempt an answer.